# Core data NSPredicate with multiple relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I need to make a fetch request, and I can't quite figure out the NSPredicate I need for the request. Here's the scenario:

I have a `List` entity, and the `list` object has a to-many relationship to a set of `Request` objects. Each `Request` object has a to-many relationship to a set of `Tags` objects.

I need perform a fetch request on the `Tags` entity, but I can't figure the `NSPredicate` for the call. I would like to only pull out the `tags` that are in all the tags of all the requests of a specific list.

Here's what I've tried:

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag in ANY list.requests.tags"];
```

But I know this isn't right. I'm not able to specify my list, also `list.requests` returns an `NSSet`, and I can't just do `.tags` on a set. I'm pretty stuck.

I've attached a pic of relationships in case that helps:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a sub-query.

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(requests, $request, $request.list = %@).@count > 0", list];
```

This counts the requests which have a specified list; if the count is more than one, the tag is taken.

You can also do:

```
[list.requests valueForKeyPath:@"tags.@distinctUnionOfSets"]
```

This uses key-value coding to retrieve all the tags that belong to all the requests and unifies them into a set. This method is less efficient than the former.

Comment: where does the 'tag' get taken into account with the above predicate?

Comment: The Tag is your entity. When you perform this predicate in a fetch request on a Tag entity, it is implicitly there. `requests` is a property on the Tag entity.

Comment: Or: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY requests.list == %@",list]` :D